# Cakephp rendres 500 error at ajax section

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I was updating a cakephp app from the  database, suddenly it started giving me a 500 error. I explored the files I found out that it's coming from ajax code:

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
     //Get filter by date box when page loads
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url: "../maps/display_time_filter_box",
         success: function(data){
             $("#time-filter-box .dropdown-menu").html(data);
             $("#mobile-time-filter-box nav").html(data);
             $(".time-slider").slider({});
         },
         error:function(xhr){
             alert("Erreur: Impossible d'afficher d'afficher le filtre");
         },
         cache: true
     });
```

Do you have any idea what could be the source of the error?

Comment: 500 errors should be logged in Cake's error logs. What do they have to say about this?

Comment: It could be caused by an error with the data being fetch by ajax. Maybe post code from */maps/display_time_filter_box* ? or maybe checking the xhr object received on the error handler ( e.g console.error(xhr) )

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use URL build to send request

```
url : "<?php echo $this->Url->build( [ 'controller' => 'Maps', 'action' => 'display_time_filter_box' ] ); ?>",
```

Comment: It was a mysql issue. In fact mysql couldn't find enough space to write the cache and it's started to render 500 errors. At a moment I couldn't access to the whole application. We are using a distant server (OVH) and we subscribed  for additional space to solve it. Thanks for your feedback.